# go back / return to / again when use any of this?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For instance.

Mexico went back to have debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982..

Mexico returned to have debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982

Mexico had again debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982

I am not sure how use go back/went back, return to/ returned, or use again when it comes to talking about you used to do before.

Answer (score 1):

### All three are perfectly fine to use, but remember that gerunds always end with *-ing*.

The choice of which to use is one of style, not grammar. However, the first two sentences use a gerund which means the verb must end in -ing. In sentence 3, the words verb and adverb are out of order*.

> **1.** Mexico went back to hav**ing** debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982.
>
> **2.** Mexico returned to hav**ing** debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982.
>
> **3.** Mexico again **had** debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982.

Also this variation of 3 would work, too:

> **4.** Mexico **had** debt problems **again** after the economic crisis in 1982.

---

*In sentence 3, the adverb "again" should come before the verb "had". But if you are using the past perfect tense (for example, "had encountered") then you could split the verb phrase:

> **5.** Mexico **had** again **encountered** debt problems after the economic crisis in 1982.

This is acceptable because "again" is still coming before the *main* verb of the phrase. "Had" is only functioning as a helper verb.

Comment: You say all three are perfectly fine and correct every single one. So, perhaps you might actually point that out.

Comment: @Lam You make a good point. I was correcting grammar related to the gerund, OP's question about the primary verb. I've edited the answer to better clarify. Thanks!